# atom unindents tab after self-closing html tag

Tags: html, atom-editor

Okay so the Atom text editor is the best thing that ever happened to me but there's something really annoying that keeps happening. Whenever I make a self-closing HTML tag like`<br/>`, atom auto-un-indents the next line, as if I had just closed an open tag and the code needed to be unindented (which it would be correct in this sense). How can I disable this?

Comment: consider reading the documentation

Comment: What packages are you using? Have you tried opening the keybinding resolver (Ctrl+.) to see if a particular package or keybinding gets activated? The other thing to check is Editor Settings -> Auto Indent.